# Multicast ICMPv6 comes back with conntrack state invalid

Tags: ipv6, netfilter, multicast, nftables, ip-conntrack

I was playing arround with the Multicast feature of IPv6.

```
$ ping ff02::2%wlp3s0
```

This should normally result in an echo-reply from all the routers on your local network segment ([Wikipedia - IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Multicast_addresses)).
So in my case my home router.

However, I found out that my original nftables rules where blocking the echo-replies:

### Original nftables rules preventing echo-reply

```
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        iifname "lo" accept
        ct state { established, related } accept
        ct state invalid drop
        ip protocol icmp accept
        ip6 nexthdr ipv6-icmp accept        
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }
}
```

With this setup no reply came through.

```
$ ping ff02::2%wlp3s0
PING ff02::2%wlp3s0(ff02::2%wlp3s0) 56 data bytes
```

### Fixed nftables rules which allowed echo-reply

```
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        iifname "lo" accept
        ct state { established, related } accept
        ip protocol icmp accept
        ip6 nexthdr ipv6-icmp accept
        ct state invalid drop
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }
}
```

With this setting it worked:

```
$ ping ff02::2%wlp3s0
PING ff02::2%wlp3s0(ff02::2%wlp3s0) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::----:----:----:----%wlp3s0: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.82 ms
```

### CT state invalid is the culprit

You might have figured out by yourself that the only difference is that once `ct state invalid drop` comes before `ip6 nexthdr ipv6-icmp accept` and once afterwards.

Thus, the echo reply to `ping ff02::2%wlp3s0` seems to have the `ct state invalid`. (I even checked this with a more specific rule and logging just to make sure)

### My Question

Shouldn't the ct state of the echo-reply be "related" ore "established", since it's a direct result of my echo-request?

If not: Why is a "normal" unicast ping (`ping 2001:470:20::2`) working in both cases?

Comment: probably it can't deduce from the initial destination IP what would be the expected reply source IP. has to be expected with multicast

Comment: That would have been my guess as well. However, isn't this a violation of the IPv6 protocol? In other words is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: it can still know that an icmp reply has to come after an icmp request. the same with UDP would have instead created a NEW state

Comment: So you're saying it's a bug?

Comment: nope. saying it's an impossible feature, or a feature that would allow too much (as in add an expectation for *any* ping reply). Also a firewall probably violates a lot of protocols, its role is to not allow things expected in the protocol, so saying that a firewall violates a protocol is perhaps a bit too much. IPv4 relies on underlying ARP (which is almost never firewalled anywhere even if it can) for link local discovery etc. IPv6 relies on ICMPv6 ie: IPv6 alone. So some things have to be blindly allowed anyway.

Comment: I totally agree with you that firewalls can break protocols. I just thought that conntrack would not, as its purpose is to abstract away the explicit state (at least that's how I understood it). I guess I should just ask on their mailing-list. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: check this SF Q/A: https://serverfault.com/questions/250797/stateful-matching-of-multicast-responses-in-iptables/911286#911286 . Interesting idea with ipset (won't help for ICMP).